# Forcing a variable to be an integer

Tags: python

```
errors = int(0)
for i in range(len(expectedData)):
    if data[i] != expectedData[i]:
        errors += int(binary_compare(data[i], expectedData[i]))
return errors
```

I have the above code which I am trying to use to calculate some integer (number of errors) for some data.  I have casted everything I can see possible as an integer, yet the line "errors += ..." still appends the value, rather than adds it.

For example, if my answer should be 7, I might get 500002.  (5 + 0 + 0 + .. + 2).  I have never run into this before.  The function binary_compare is returning an integer as well, but I'm completely in the dark as to why this isn't working.

Comment: May not be related, but I would use `return sum(binary_compare(x, y) for x, y in zip(data, expectedData) if x != y)` instead.

Comment: Can you post the code? Try to post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the error.

Comment: You should also use `xrange` over `range`, since the latter creates another list in memory whereas the former just iterates.

Comment: @Daenyth: Except in Python ≥3.

Comment: @Dayneth: OP should probably be using neither.

Comment: @SilentGhost yes, it is.

Comment: I cannot duplicate what you're seeing with the exact same code (substituting a mock `binary_compare` function and a pair of mismatched strings for the two data lists). Is this actually the code that's exhibiting the problem?

Comment: @ahhtwer: Try to insert `print(repr(errors))` after each modification to `errors` and edit your post to show the result.

Comment: @ahhtwer.  Since no one can reproduce your problem, the "yes it is all the code" claim must be false.  Odds are good that you've butchered the `int` function in some horrible way.

Comment: interesting, doing the sum + zip seemed to fix the problem.  Thanks KennyTM

Comment: This is when you ask KennyTM to post the comment as an answer so you can accept it... http://stackoverflow.com/faq (see "How do I ask questions here?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is outside of your code, but anyway, in Python, list operations are seldom done with loops, as this focuses on the implementation rather on the purpose. List comprehension, generators etc are preferred, and there are also many built-in and standard library functions for common tasks.

In your case, I would write the function as

```
return sum(binary_compare(x, y) for x, y in zip(data, expectedData) if x != y)
```

If you are using Python 2.x, [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) should be used instead of `zip`.

Answer (score 4):

python is not javascript

it's no way to get concatenated strings instead of math sum, when you do `count += value` starting with `count = 0`. if you try to add a string to integer, exception is raised:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> x += "1"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

to compare values of which you don't know whether they are strings or integers, i'd use

```
str(data[i]).strip() == str(expectedData[i]).strip()
```

for noninteger-proof math sum, you might want to do something like this

```
try:
    value = int(expectedData[i])
except:
    value = 0
count += value
```